# Beginner Python 3 Manjaro Linux/Windows text auto formating project

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, text, printing, odfpy

This is my first project so I am not experienced. I am trying to make a program for my Mom that will download a recipe of off a website like jamiecooksitup.net, recognize sections of the recipe(description, ingredients, instructions) format it(font,text size, placement of text, etc) and then spit it out as a .odt file with the option to send it to the printer. It would be nice if there was some option that could be added to Google Chrome to do this. Maybe my program could show up as a printer? It should open a GUI that lets you chose where to save the file and if you would like to print it out. It also needs to work both on Windows and KDE Manjaro (expecting to make two versions). I have already decided to use odfpy for formatting and outputting the file, but I can not find a good tutorial. I need suggestions for any other APIs as well as how the program should generally work. I am a beginner so i would like to learn from this project. I need to get better.

Edit: I just completed the W3schools tutorial a bit ago and have been practicing. I don't know enough to do this, I am trying to do it to learn. So I need to know how to: take text and images of of a webpage, text processing with odfpy, how to make a Gui, how to send commands to a printer and just generally how to be good at programing.

Comment: The project you are embarking on is not a trivial thing. For a beginner, I recommend you take it slowly. You have already broken down a few components of the project. Why not set smaller milestones to tackle each one of them? There won't be a tutorial specifically tailored to your project, but there are a lot of tutorials on how to take text and images of a webpage (i.e. web scraping), make a GUI (you can try pygame), etc. Work on the smaller milestones first, and then think about how to piece them together for the big boy project at the end.

Comment: It does appear to be more complicated then I thought. I'll start with web scraping for now. But if you know of a good tutorial for odfpy a link would be appreciated. Also any suggestions for a good api for webscraping?

Comment: Real Python has good tutorials for a lot of Python topics. I will start from [here](https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/). Later, you can try [a more powerful tool](https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/).